# Objects and lists, python

Tags: python, class

I'm new to python/pygame. I want to define my own class. This class takes a list within a list and a acceleration function. I want to call these functions in another class so that they can be changed/ manipulated.

This is what i have:

```
Class baddie():
    def __init__(self):
        self._list=([random.randint(100,210),530])
    def accelaration(self,acc):
        clock=300-(acc)
```

I then want the baddie class to be called in the space class. So the user can manipulate the two above functions.

```
Class space():
    b = baddie()
    b.accelaration(203)
```

I also want the user to be able to call the list which takes a random integer and another number, but I don't understand how.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Whats wrong with your current code?

Comment: (FWIW *acceleration* has two 'e's and one 'a'.)

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

class baddie():
    def __init__(self):
        self._list=([random.randint(100,210),530])
    def accelaration(self,acc):
        clock=300-(acc)

class space():
    b = baddie()
    b.accelaration(203)
    print b._list       # This is how we print the _list

space()
```

`_list` is just an instance variable, which holds a tuple. So you can simply access it with `b._list`

**Note:** As suggested by `kojiro` in the comments section, try to change your variable name to something more meaningful to your application than `_list`. Since you are a beginner, I recommend reading this atleast once http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/.

Comment: Technically true, but variable names starting with an underscore are [by convention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) for internal use. So perhaps the fix is to lose the underscore (and use a name other than `list`) or write a @property getter.

Comment: @kojiro Added a note in the answer :)